# Csvsimple with nonenglish: error

Tags: tables, csvsimple

Trying to parse table with russian symbols. Example csv file:

```
Название, Автор, Год
Бесы, Достоевский, 1871
```

Can't create a table from this file with any command: `\csvloop`, `\csvautotabular{table.csv}`, `\csvautobooktabular{table.csv}`. While if everything is in English — works perfect.
File `table.csv` UTF-8 encoded, document uses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`.

These are the errors:

```
! Package csvsimple Error: File 'table.csv' starts with an empty line!.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
! Extra \endcsname.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@temp
```

Can't find anything in documentation or elsewhere in the Tex forums on this problem.

Example .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ncc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{table.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add a small LaTeX file that shows the issue, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @egreg Sure. I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two orders of problems.

1. The first row is also used to give symbolic names to the columns, but Cyrillic characters cannot appear in command names. Possibly this can be solved by options not to interpret the first line.
2. Cyrillic characters seem to thoroughly confuse `csvsimple`; you'd need to brace each entry.

My suggestion is to use XeLaTeX.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Название, Автор, Год
Бесы, Достоевский, 1871
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ncc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{\jobname.csv}
\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` and a different name for the CSV file just not to clobber my files and to make the example self-contained.

[image]